# No funciona AutoPoskback de DropDownList en UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

Se tiene un control de usuario el cual implementa un control de usuario, este control de usuario interno tiene un UpdatePanel y un DropDownList con la propiedad AutoPoskback igual a **true**. El control de usuario principal tiene un botón que realiza las validaciones correspondiente; pero después de que se ejecuta el evento del botón el muestra correctamente el caracter "*" para indicar que es requerido, pero el AutoPostback del DropDownList  deja de funcionar; funciona la segunda vez de seleccionar un item de la lista desplegable.

Control de usuario Interno

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DdlVariable" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" SkinID="skinDropDownList" Width="90%" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Dynamic"
                ErrorMessage="*"
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="7.5pt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="3" SkinID="skinTextBoxContenido" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Se tiene el control de usuario principal que implementa al control de usuario anterior, y el botón que lanza las validaciones.

```
<div>
    <wuc:WucVariable runat="server" ID="WucVariable1" TituloLabelVariable="Variable 2" ValidationGroup="ModCombinada" UpdateMode="Conditional" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" SkinID="skinImgAceptar" ValidationGroup="ModCombinada" />
</div>
```

El DropDownList tiene su evento el cual lo unico que hace es una consulta para conocer un parametro, y al final registrar un script para lanzar la función de Javascript. Es importante decir que estoy implementando la función javascript **ValidatorEnable** para habilitar o inhabilitar las validaciones de ciertos campos.

El principal error, es que si lanzó el evento clic del botón; este ejecuta las validaciones tanto de los controles que estan el control de usuario principal como de los controles que estan en el control de usuario interno. Pero después de de que se lanzan las validaciones deja de funcionar el autoposkback del DropDownList, claro esta al hacer el primer intento del autoPostBack, ya después del segundo intento funciona nuevamente el AutoPoskback. No sé como hacer para que no me deshabilite el autoPostBack en ningún momento.

Comment: Has probado a añadir el atributo 'CausesValidation="true"' a tu DropDownList?

Comment: Lo probé, pero sigue presentando el mismo comportamiento.

Comment: Tienes una master page? podría ser que algún control de esa master tenga un autopostback que haga que el de la página no se ejecute (o se ejecute más tarde)? no sé, por dar ideas